# Post default BindProperty data to Razor Page using JQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-2.1, razor-pages

I am trying to post data using ajax request to Asp.Net Core 2.1 Razor Page.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/MyPage",
    data: { "Key1": Val1},
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    },
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (response) {
        if (response == "Success")
            alert("Successfully saved.");
        else {
            alert(response);
        }
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert(e.responseText);
    }
});
```

Here everything works well.

Now, I want to pass approx 50 textbox's values, so instead of using `data: { "Key1": Val1},` Is there any alternative to bind `[BindProperty] class`?

My PageModel looks

```
[BindProperty]
public InputModel Input { get; set; }
```

More Info on .cshtml

https://jsfiddle.net/4sb8vqda/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [serialize method](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/MyPage",
    headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
    data: $('#theFormId').serialize(),
    success: function (response) {
        if (response == "Success")
            alert("Successfully saved.");
        else {
            alert(response);
        }
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert(e.responseText);
    }
});
```

You are setting the wrong header value. Also, don't set the `contenttype` to `false`. That causes the `contenttype` to be set to `text/plain` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` which you need to transfer the form values.

Comment: Values are null with this.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your form's HTML?

Comment: @Ramesh updated my answer based on your posted fiddle.